# XML nodes with root not working in VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

The below code works fine with XML 1 but doesn't read rows from XML 2 (ROOT added). Do you know why?

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("test.xml")

set  nodes=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer")
for i=0 to nodes.length-1
set node = nodes(i)
set company = node.selectSingleNode("company")
msgbox company
next
```

XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
    <customer>
        <name>ABCars</firma>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

XML 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT xmlns="http://www.something.com ">
    <customers>
        <customer>
            <name>ABCars</firma>
        </customer>
    </customers>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because your second document has a default namespace.  XPath is funky with default namespaces.  You need either need to add a namespace prefix (e.g. `xmlns:ns0="http://www.something.com"` and then use that prefix (`ns0:ROOT`, `ns0:customers`, etc.), or refactor your XPath to use the `local-name()` function:

```
set nodes=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='customer']")
```

You'll also have to change your selectSingleNode:

```
set company = node.selectsingleNode("*[local-name()='company']")
```

If you search this site for "XPath default namespace" you'll find a lot of related questions.

Comment: Many thanks! One more thing - if I use the syntax: set nodes=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name(.) = 'customer']") how can I get customer name value? set company = node.selectSingleNode("name") doesn't seems to work any more.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  If this answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkbox under it.